# merge files into one on xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp

We have order files that are date time stamped like so
28072010_950_order.txt
28072010_1050_order.txt

does anybody know how to, on a windows xp box, have a small app run that would change all these time stamped files that have the same date and merge them into a single file called:
28072010_order.txt

So it would take all the data from all these single files and merge it into one file.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you asking for a programming solution? If so, you seem to have forgotten what language you are using. If not, this is not the right place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple batch file that contains a command like this.

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do type %%f >> file.txt
```